# Why are fractional data types generally not implemented?

Tags: c++, c, types

I have been working with C/C++ for quite a few years. I have also worked with few other programming languages but none have built-in fractional datatypes. Here I am not talking about the regular decimal datatypes like float. I am referring to regular mathematical fractions having the following form:

Nr/Dr where Dr≠0

What are the challenges that are faced by the developers in implementing such datatypes?

Comment: Aside: `float` is not a decimal data type, it is implemented in binary. Indeed, it represents decimals rather poorly, for example `1/10` has no exact representation.

Comment: People tend to reach for fractions as a crutch to avoid thinking about floating point precision issues, and then they get hit by fraction limitations instead. No irrationals, you run out of precision quickly, all the benefits disappear as soon as you need any sort of approximation-based algorithm (and numerical computing is full of those)...

Comment: @WeatherVane OP seems to be using a colloquial meaning of "decimal", which is "not just whole numbers".

Comment: A problem in implementing rational arithmetic is that arithmetic operations tend to increase the denominator: Adding 1/4 and 1/3 produces 1/12. This can quickly overflow the integer type used for the denominator, and guarding against it would require cumbersome run-time code. And when the limit is reached, the arithmetic must either break or change to an approximation. And that point, you have largely an equivalent of fixed-point or floating-point arithmetic, and nothing much has been accomplished.

Comment: Wolfram Language has built-in fractional datatype. Just enter e.g. `x=14/6`, and `x` will be set to `7/3`. C++ has [`boost::multiprecision::*rational`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/rational.html) (which is, although not built-in, but very portable).

Comment: Additionally, rational arithmetic cannot support square root, sine, logarithm, and so on. The mathematics that can be performed is quite limited.

Comment: @Ruslan Mathematica and the Wolfram Language are meant to be used primarily as a symbolic manipulation engine (yes, it has a lot of numerical capabilities too). Totally different use cases compared to a systems programming language like C or C++.

Comment: @Acorn yes, that's why it's built-in to WL, and only a third-party library in C++. But Python [has them built-in](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html).

Comment: C's data types are basically what the CPU can use directly, and structs. C doesn't have a fractional datatype because your CPU doesn't have fractional data instructions. (Also I think these are often called "rational" rather than "fractional")

Comment: Have a look at the `CGAL` library (it includes arbitrary precision fractions) https://www.cgal.org/

Comment: @user253751 that's a poor explanation. CPU doesn't have an instruction to multiply/divide complex numbers, yet C has built-in `_Complex` type (since C99).

Comment: The GNU Multi Precision Arithmetic Library ([GNU MP](https://gmplib.org/)) supports rational numbers with its `mpq_t` type. It's a bit of a pain to use from C. The C++ class interface (`mpq_class`) is easier to use as it defines arithmetic operators.

Comment: @Ruslan and that was a mistake IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Builtin data types tend to be those that are widely useful, and map more or less efficiently to the underlying architecture. This is no hard and fast rule, but it’s a pretty good rule of thumb.

Fractional data types are neither: they *would* be widely useful, but limited-precision floating-point types are good enough for 99.9% <sup>(or 999/1000, if you prefer)</sup> of applications, can be implemented much more efficiently due to hardware support, and have far fewer theoretical and practical limitations because they represent a more general domain of numbers (i.e. not just operations on rational numbers).

There *are* specific applications where floating point data types don’t cut it, and where arbitrary-precision rational numbers are needed. For those cases, special libraries exist. Cluttering standard libraries with these types would be a waste of effort.

So, essentially, the answer is the same as for any other specialised data type that isn’t widely implemented as a built-in type.

Comment: Floating point numbers are actually less general; all floating point numbers are rational numbers, but with lower precision.

Comment: @user253751 Sure, but they naturally represent approximations, and are expected to. The whole point of rational numbers is that they represent exact values, not approximations. Once you use them to represent approximations for irrational numbers, their last advantage over limited-precision floating-point values goes out of the window. Put differently, a rational fraction data type is *expected* to represent the domain rational numbers. A floating-point data type, by contrast, is expected to represent an approximation of arbitrary real numbers.

Answer (score 5):

> What are the challenges that are faced by the developers in implementing such datatypes?

It is not because it is a challenge, but because they are not that useful in practice.

*Unlimited* precision rationals are way more useful, but that implies managing memory and using smart algorithms to have as good performance as possible. At that point, you are better served implementing the functionality as a full-fledged math library like GNU GMP and friends rather than a built-in type.

Answer (score 2):

> What are the challenges that are faced by the developers in implementing such datatypes?

It's really tedious to duplicate everything you can do with `int`.

The `fraction` type has to be pervasive across all the libraries you wish to use, or you end up switching back and forth between `fraction` and builtin types

Comment: The biggest disadvantage of the current representation of fractions in programming languages is loss of precision. I mean representation of numerator and denominator seperately would overcome this limitation. Eg. 5/7 = 0.7142857...

Comment: @RahulDixit You can store that as a fixed-point number, no need for fractions.

Comment: @RahulDixit that leaves you with a much larger limitation on the denominator. Floating-point numbers can have ranges from `1e-308` to `1e+308` for `float64`, while similarly-sized rational will be limited to the range from `2e-10` to `4e9`.

Comment: @Acorn: Fixed point isn't going to help you represent 5/7.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Depends on what point you fix on :)

Comment: I agree to the fact that they can be implemented somehow using integers. But this will require so much extra code from our side: reducing fractions to lowest form, equality comparisons, inequality comparisons and conversions from improper to mixed form or vice versa. If there would have been implemented by default, it would have been a lot easier.

Comment: An example of where it is being used: Open Google Calculator for Android. Type 14/6. It will show the result both in decimal and fractional forms. 2.33333... and 7/3.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica You need to keep how long the recurring part is, yeah.